# How to set a specific field of boolean array to false

Tags: java

I have a class called Labyrinth and here I have `private boolean[][] manual = new boolean[21][21];`. How to make the setter to this array so I can do something like this, so the field on x,y coordinates sets to false?:

```
Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth();
labyrinth.setManual(labyrinth.getLabyrinth[x][y]);
```

Comment: Why can't you use `manual[x][y] = false;`?

Comment: `manual[x][y] = false` will set it to `false`

Comment: Do you mean like `public void setManual(int x, int y) { this.manual[x][y] = true; }`?

Comment: Or `public void setManual(int x, int y, boolean value) { this.manual[x][y] = value; }`

Comment: I want to set the manual value in a different class... @CoffeehouseCoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned by [saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279/saka1029) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795507/how-to-set-a-specific-field-of-boolean-array-to-false#comment86605344_49795507), you can create a method inside your labyrinth class that will set `manual[x][y]` to the value you want.

```
public class Labyrinth {
    private boolean[][] manual = new boolean[21][21];

    //Your stuff

    public void setManual(int x, int y, boolean value) {
        this.manual[x][y] = value;
    }

}
```

And to call it

```
Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth();
labyrinth.setManual(x, y, false);
```